# What is the Fourier series of $\sin(1/x)$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

What is the Fourier series of $\sin(1/x)$ (or $x^k\sin(1/x)$, where $k$ is a positive integer) in $[-\pi,\pi]$? This function evidently does not satisfy Dirichlet's conditions. However, Dirichlet's conditions are known to be sufficient but not necessary for the convergence of Fourier series. Is there any book (not too sophisticated) where the convergence of the Fourier series of these functions is mentioned or the series is given explicitly? The only reference I have found where the expansibility of $\sin(1/x)$ in Fourier series is mentioned is "Mathematical methods in the physical sciences" by M. L Boas (2005) (Chapter 7, page 358). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dini criterion shows that the Fourier series of $f$ converges at every point of differentiability for $f$ so in particular at any $x \in (-\pi, \pi), x \ne 0$ for the above; since the function is odd, its Fourier series is a sine series so is $0$ at $\pm \pi, 0$

Answer (score 9):

The Fourier series of $\sin(1/x)$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ does not have a closed-form expression, but the Fourier transform in $\mathbb{R}$ does have it, in terms of a Bessel function:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(kx)\sin(1/x)\,dx=\pi k^{-1/2}J_1(2\sqrt{k}),\;\;k>0.$$
The transform is odd in $k$ with a discontinuous jump of $2\pi$ at $k=0$.

[image]

Comment: Is "Fourier series in $\mathbb R$" also known as "Fourier transform"?

Comment: indeed it is --- thanks.

Comment: The Fourier series in $[-\pi,\pi]$ is then the convolution of that Fourier transform with the sinc function, the sinc function being the Fourier transform of the characteristic function for $[-\pi,\pi]$ by which $\sin(1/x)$ is truncated.

Comment: If I got elementary changes of variables right, the Fourier Transform of $\sin(1/x)$ can also be computed and plotted with PARI/GP by typing $$\mathtt{F(w) = -2/(2*Pi*w)*intnumosc(t=1,sin(1/t)*sin(2*Pi*w*t)/t/t,1/(2*w),1)-2*intnumosc(t=1,sin(1/t)*sin(2*Pi*w*t),1/(2*w),1)}$$ and $$\mathtt{ploth(w=1e-10, 10, F(w))}$$ where $w$ relates to Carlo Beenakker's $k$ by $w = \frac{k}{2\pi}$.

Comment: ... my numerical plot looks like Carlo Beenakker's answer when plotted but doesn't match for its pseudo-period and limit value at $0^+$. I must have made an elementary mistake.